# PHPExcel cant read the other worksheet... i dont know why doesnt work

Tags: php, phpexcel

I dont know what is the problem in my code. I read some code in internet and I think my code is fine but when I choose a second worksheet it didnt work. any one can help me out to check what is the problem in my code.

PS: I use `$objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);` to see the other worksheet and its fine

Here is my code where I set to choose in second worksheet:

```
try {
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
            $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($worksheetname); 

            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }



        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($worksheetname);
        // $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();  
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
```

THANKS IN ADVANCED GUYS !

Comment: "t didnt work", can you be more specific?

Comment: Does the worksheet you're actually trying to load actually exist in the workbook?

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys i appreciate your help yes sir your correct the workbook doesnt exist the file have a problem not my code